# Using awk, how to average numbers in column between two strings in a text file

Tags: awk

A text file containing multiple tabular delimited columns between strings with an example below.

```
Code 1 (3)
5     10      7      1      1
6     10      9      1      1
7     10     10      1      1
Code 2 (2)
9     11      3      1      3
10     8      5      2      1
Code 3 (1)
12    10      2      1      1
Code 4 (2)
14     8      1      1      3
15     8      7      5      1
```

I would like to average the numbers in the third column for each code block. The example below is what the output should look like.

```
8.67
4
2
4
```

**Attempt 1**

```
awk '$3~/^[[:digit:]]/ {i++; sum+=$3; print $3} $3!~/[[:digit:]]/ {print sum/i; sum=0;i=0}' in.txt
```

Returned `fatal: division by zero attempted`.

**Attempt 2**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/^Code/ { if (NR > 1) {i++; sum+=$3;} {print sum/i;}}' in.txt
```

Returned another division by zero error.

**Attempt 3**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/^Code/ { if (NR > 1) { print s/i; s=0; i=0; } else { s += $3; i += 1; }}' in.txt
```

Returned 1 value: `0`.

**Attempt 4**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/^Code/ {
   if (NR > 1)
      i++
      print sum += $3/i
}
END {
   i++
   print sum += $3/i
}'
```

Returned:

```
0
0
0
0.3
```

I am not sure where that last number is coming from, but this has been the closest solution so far. I am getting a number for each block, but not the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^Code/{
  if(value!=0 && value){
    print sum/value
  }
  sum=value=""
  next
}
{
  sum+=$NF;
  value++
}
END{
  if(value!=0 && value){
    print sum/value
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: I got it to work for a column by changing the $NF to $3 for the sum. Thank you for steering me in the right direction.